# Проверка важной почты через cURL

Tags: c++, curl, gmail, imap

У меня есть программка, которая при наличии непрочитанной почты на GMail мигает иконкой-уведомлением. Просто наличие почты по POP3 через URL `pop3s://pop.gmail.com` я получаю, но теперь хочу исправить программу и мигать только если есть именно важная мне почта - по from.

Так что хочу добиться следующей функциональности на С++ с использованием cURL - есть аккаунт GMail, я хочу заходить туда, смотреть *непрочитанные* письма - чтобы понимать, от кого они, и если там есть что-то от важных мне отправителей - давать Notify иконку. При этом почта не должна быть затронута - ну, в смысле, ели зайти почтовой программой по POP3 - то она ее заберет.

Как при этом быть с почтой? Как я понимаю, по POP3 ее нельзя забирать - помешаю почтовой программе.

Наверное, надо через IMAP? Подскажите, как на С++ залезть в GMail, посмотреть входящую непрочитанную почту и скачать заголовки (меня интересует в первую очередь from этих писем), но при этом чтоб не мешать GMail ее потом отдать по POP3. Если покажите где-то пример и описание - было бы отлично.

Пока с таким

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, "imaps://imap.gmail.com/INBOX/");
```

захожу и ответ получаю, но что в нем искать и как - что-то найти не могу.

Answer (score 1):

По POP3 протоколу можно все узнать по перечню сообщений в почтовом ящике и это никак не повлияет на работу почтовой программы, если только вы сами не пометите сообщение для удаления.
Я даже не знал, что curl поддерживает pop3, но попробуйте поэкспериментировать с командами, передаваемые в заголовках апи, вот к примеру, удаление письма:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
 
int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res = CURLE_OK;
 
  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    /* Set username and password */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERNAME, "user");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PASSWORD, "secret");
 
    /* You can specify the message either in the URL or DELE command */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "pop3://pop.example.com/1");
 
    /* Set the DELE command */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELE");
 
    /* Do not perform a transfer as DELE returns no data */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1L);
 
    /* Perform the custom request */
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
 
    /* Check for errors */
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
      fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
              curl_easy_strerror(res));
 
    /* Always cleanup */
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
 
  return (int)res;
}
```

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/POP3 Тут примеры команд и ссылки на RFC.

Comment: Ну, мне надо pop3s - для Gmail'а, но это второй вопрос. Главное - мне через pop3 придется забирать всю почту, чтоб узнать, от кого она, а я хочу выяснять это, не перекачивая всё подряд.

Comment: Отправьте команду LIST таким способом и сервер должен выдать список всех сообщений, без скачивания, только заголовки.
Если был передан аргумент, то сервер выдаёт информацию об указанном сообщении. Если аргумент не был передан, то сервер выдаёт информацию обо всех сообщениях, находящихся в почтовом ящике. Сообщения, помеченные для удаления, не перечисляются.
[сообщение] — номер сообщения (необязательный аргумент).

Comment: pop3s указать в адресе вместо pop3 думаю то же не проблема